# Firebase denormalized data vs Redux normalized state?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, nosql

Given an example nested data below:

(multiple) users

a user has (multiple) trips

a trip has (multiple) days

a day has a date, and (multiple) visits

a visit has a time, and a location

a location has location specific meta data

At each step it's all '1 to Many' relationship except for the end of tree where a location can be shared by different visits/ days/ trips/ users

It looks like [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) can normalize/ flatten this data for use as Redux state. But what structure should the data take for its copy in Firebase?

Firebase recommends that data should be denormalized and flattened. But doesn't denormalization mean returning a completely nested structure? I'm getting quite confused about pulling things together with Redux and Firebase so any clarification is greatly appreciated.

```
  users: {
    user_1: {
      trips: {
        trip_1: {
          days: {
            day_1: {
              date: certain_date
              visits: {
                visit_1: {
                  time: certain_time,
                  loc: {
                    id: certain_location_id,
                    ...
                  }
                },
                visit_2: {...},
                ...  
              }
            },
            day_2: {...},
            ...
          }
        },
        trip_2: {...},
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Denormalizing means exactly the opposite of the nesting you do. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data and specifically https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout.

Comment: Thanks for the materials. now a slight unrelated question, if in firebase I have attached listeners to the children of a parent node, when I delete the parent node, what will happen to the listeners of the children?

Comment: They will get invoked with the updates (so a null `value` or `child_removed`). That's pretty much it.